flutter_web i10n causing 'unexpected null value'
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

return MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
      AppLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    supportedLocales: L10n.all,
    locale: const Locale('en'),
    title: "INTERNEAL",
    home: Column(
      children: [
        Text("F FLUTTERRRRR"),
        Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld)
      ],
    ));

is my main.dart file
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
nullable-getter: false

l10n.yaml file.
{
  "helloWorld": "Hello World!",
  "@helloWorld": {
    "description": "The conventional newborn programmer greeting"
  },
}

And, this is to set the setting.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class L10n {
  static final all = [
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('kr'),
  ];
}

I've followed everything that I could. And, it is giving me 'unexpected null value'. I am currently using flutter_web but I don't think it is because of the web?
Is there any alternative to this? I really don't understand why it is this much complicated to just internationalising but yeah. How can I fix this?
